# What is going wrong? Nothing is printing in Python

Tags: python, dice

## My assignment is in Python 3.3.2 and it is here:

Create a class for a dice object that can randomly generate a number between 1 and 6 and save the file.

You will need the random module and

Create 2 Dice objects a and b and add their values together.

Here are the rules

Win = total equals 7 or 11

Lose = total equals 2,3 or 12

Roll again = total equals 5,6,8,9,10 until a 7 is rolled or the same number is thrown again.

---

Now the code I have written:

```
import random

class Dice:
    '''A class that makes Dice'''

    number = random.randint(1,6)

a = Dice
b = Dice

result = a.number + b.number

def resultgiver():
    if result == '7':
        result == '11'
        print('You won! You got ' ,result,'.')

    elif result == '2':
        result == '3'
        result == '12'
        print('You lost! You got ' ,result,'.')

    elif result == '5':
        result == '6'
        result == '8'
        result == '9'
        result == '10'
        print('Roll again! You got ' ,result,'.')

    elif result == '5':
        result == '6'
        result == '8'
        result == '9'
        result == '10'

    elif result == '7':
        result == '11'

resultgiver()
```

Comment: Try instantiating Dice for `a` and `b`, e.g. a = Dice(). Note also that Dice.number will always be the same - the random is evaluated only at import.  You probably want to put this in the \_\_init\_\_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems:

1. you need parentheses around your class instances:

`a = Dice()` and
`b = Dice()`

1. `result` is an integer yet all your if statments check if it equals a char. remove all the quotes around your the numbers

   if result == 5:
2. you need an init in your class so you always get a different number when you instantiate the class.

   class Dice:
           '''A class that makes Dice'''

   ```
       def __init__(self):
           self.number = random.randint(1,6)
   ```

try putting a else at the end to catch any result that is not 7 or 5:

```
elif result == '7':
        result == '11'
else:
    print "we got here"
```

I think you are trying to emulate a switch statement with your if statement. The way you did wont work but try this:

```
def resultgiver():
    if result in [7,11]:
        print('You won! You got ' ,result,'.')

    elif result in [2, 3, 12]:
        print('You lost! You got ' ,result,'.')

    elif result in [5, 6, 8, 9, 10]:
        print('Roll again! You got ' ,result,'.')

    else:
        print "default case for result =", result
```

Comment: I tried this but still nothing. Thank you for helping though! Oh no wait you changed it and part 2 of your answer helps! Thank you so much!

Comment: Inside each `if` block, it's not clear why there are a series `result == num` lines.  There is something going wrong there as well.

Comment: @SethMMorton you are right, I think OP was trying to emulate the function of a switch statement. Anyways I updated my answer to show a potential approach to achieve that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

> What is going wrong? Nothing is printing in Python

You only print anything if the result is 7, 2, or 5, AND for some reason if it is a string (and it's never a string, because you don't convert it to a string). You only set result once, in global scope, so re-running the function doesn't change anything.

Learn about function parameters. You want to pass the number result to your function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

and you should write

```
if result == 2 or result == 3 or result == 4:
```

etc to check two or more conditions.
also a.number always equals always b.number, because you assign a value to Dice.number only once.
try this:

```
class Dice(random.Random):
    def number(self):
        return self.randint(1, 6)
a = Dice()
b = Dice()
result = a.number() + b.number()
```

Comment: When should `result == 2 and result == 3 and result == 4` ever be true?

Comment: very sry, was intending to write result == 2 **or** result == 3 etc., i will edit my answer

Comment: things like this happen when you Focus on Syntax and Forget the logic. but you have to admit, my Statement is valid

Answer (score 1):

Since this *is* homework, I'd recommend reading about:

- [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)
- [Python class instantiation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)
- [Python variable types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm)

You are doing something wrong in each of these areas in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You compare string with integer !!

```
if result == '7':
```

---

I think in this code

```
if result == '7':
    result == '11'
    print('You won! You got ' ,result,'.')
```

you want do this

```
if result == 7 or result == 11 :
    print('You won! You got ' ,result,'.')
```